# C++ ~ call to function in client gives error: "identifier ____ is undefined"

Tags: c++, file, client, undefined, identifier

I'm coming to you with a problem that has several different files involved. I'm not sure why I'm getting the error specified in the title. Let me put the files below and go from there.

DummyClient.cpp

```
#include "Gameboard.h"          //for Gameboard
#include "Location.h"           //for function prototypes
#include "zList.h"              //for Zombies
#include <iostream>             //for input/output stream

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    srand(123456789);

    Gameboard myGB;

    myGB = Gameboard();

    ZombieListClass();

    ZombieRec zombieList[MAX_ZOMBIES];

    PopulateZombies(zombieList[MAX_ZOMBIES]); // this throws the error here of "Error: identifier "PopulateZombies" is undefined"

}
```

zList.h

```
#ifndef ZLIST_H
#define ZLIST_H

#include "Location.h"   // for list record
#include "ZombieRec.h"
#include "Gameboard.h"

class ZombieListClass
{

    public:
      ZombieListClass();            //default constructor 

      void PopulateZombies(ZombieRec zombieList[]);

      bool IsInBounds(int row, int col);


    private:
      ZombieRec list[MAX_ZOMBIES];      //stores the items in the list
      int length;                           //# of values currently in the list
      int currPos;                      //position of current element
      int strength;                 // health and attack units of a zombie

};

#endif
```

zList.cpp

```
#include "zList.h"

ZombieListClass::ZombieListClass()      //default constructor 
{

    length = 0;
    currPos = 0;
    strength = 5;
    LocationRec zombieLoc;

}

void ZombieListClass::PopulateZombies(ZombieRec zombieList[])
{
    int row, col;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ZOMBIES; i++)
    {
        row = rand() % MAX_ROW + 1;
        col = rand() % MAX_COL + 1;

        while (!IsInBounds(row, col))
        {
            row = rand() % MAX_ROW + 1;
            col = rand() % MAX_COL + 1;
        }

        zombieList[i].currLoc.row = row;
        zombieList[i].currLoc.col = col;

    }


}

bool ZombieListClass::IsInBounds(int row, int col)
{

    if (row == 0 || row == MAX_ROW + 1 || col == 0 || col == MAX_COL + 1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Gameboard.h

```
#ifndef GAMEBOARD_H
#define GAMEBOARD_H


#include "Location.h" 
#include "ZombieRec.h"
#include "zList.h"


const int MAX_ROW = 3;      // total number of rows in the board
const int MAX_COL = 3;      // total number of cols in the board



class Gameboard
{

public:

    Gameboard();


private:
    int boardSizeArr[MAX_ROW + 2][MAX_COL + 2];


}; // end Gameboard

#endif
```

and finally, Gameboard.cpp

```
#include "Gameboard.h"

Gameboard::Gameboard()
{

    // Declares a board with a boundary along the outside
    boardSizeArr[MAX_ROW + 2][MAX_COL + 2]; 

}
```

I'm not looking to be spoonfed and for somebody to solve my problem for me, I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong so that the remainder of my project isn't as bumpy as it has been this whole time.

Looking back on my error, "identifer "PopulateZombies" is undefined", I can't imagine why it is. Could this have something to do with the scope of how I'm doing things? If I've left any code out (I didn't put everything in there but I think I have everything relevant) just let me know, I'm able to converse back and forth as long as this takes.

Thank you to everybody in advance that tries to help :)

-Anthony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you call the function using a variable, instead of calling it directly if defined in a class:

```
ZombieListClass zombieList=new ZombieListClass();  // add a variable here

ZombieRec zombieList[MAX_ZOMBIES];

zombieList.PopulateZombies(zombieList[MAX_ZOMBIES]); // See the difference?
```

Comment: You know, right after I posted the question I looked at the Gameboard myGB; right above it in the client file. I feel so dumb sometimes to overlook that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether the error you posted is the only error. Here is what I see in your main.cpp

```
#include "Gameboard.h"          //for Gameboard
#include "Location.h"           //for function prototypes
#include "zList.h"              //for Zombies
#include <iostream>             //for input/output stream

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    srand(123456789);

    Gameboard myGB;

    myGB = Gameboard();//The constructor"Gameboard()" is automatically called when you defined 
                       //myGB in the previous line,

    ZombieListClass();//see Hai Bi's great answer on this one

    ZombieRec zombieList[MAX_ZOMBIES];//ZombieRec is a member of ZombieListClass, use . to access it

    PopulateZombies(zombieList[MAX_ZOMBIES]); //Also see  Hai Bi's answer

}
```

My advice is to revisit the concept of [constructor and class definition](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/) before put your hands on s a problem like this.